An ImageButton with rounded corners does not display well
I am developing an application in .NET MAUI using Visual Studio 2022. Generally it works fine, but at some point something got corrupted and a particular button on a screen is not displayed correctly. The XAML code would be as follows:
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
             HorizontalOptions="End">
    <ImageButton Source="Icons/close.png"
                 BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Neutral085}"
                 HeightRequest="36"
                 WidthRequest="36"
                 CornerRadius="18"
                 Padding="6"
                 Margin="0,10,15,10"
                 Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"/>
</StackLayout>

It is an ImageButton with rounded edges. But it is displayed as a square and smaller in size:

This same XAML code on another screen is displayed correctly. If I run the app from Visual Studio and repeat the button with the Hot Reload I see that the new buttons are displayed correctly.
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
             HorizontalOptions="End">
    <ImageButton Source="Icons/close.png"
                 BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Neutral085}"
                 HeightRequest="36"
                 WidthRequest="36"
                 CornerRadius="18"
                 Padding="6"
                 Margin="0,10,15,10"
                 Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"/>
    <ImageButton Source="Icons/close.png"
                 BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Neutral085}"
                 HeightRequest="36"
                 WidthRequest="36"
                 CornerRadius="18"
                 Padding="6"
                 Margin="0,10,15,10"
                 Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"/>
    <ImageButton Source="Icons/close.png"
                 BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Neutral085}"
                 HeightRequest="36"
                 WidthRequest="36"
                 CornerRadius="18"
                 Padding="6"
                 Margin="0,10,15,10"
                 Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"/>
</StackLayout>


I don't know why this is happening, I guess there is some corrupted intermediate code/object that is cached somewhere and this is used instead of newly generated code. I have tried the following and it hasn't solved the problem:

Uninstalling the app from the mobile and reinstalling.
Clean the solution, delete the bin and obj folders and re-generate the solution.

What could be happening?
Edit:
More information:

.NET MAUI version: 8.0
Microsoft.Maui.Controls version: 8.0.70


.NET Maui version and Microsoft.Maui.Controls version please

@FreakyAli information added to question

So this only happens with this one ImageButton in on a single screen and everywhere else it works fine?

@FreakyAli Yes, that exactly.

Is there a user folder in which cached objects or references can be stored?

try removing bin and obj

@FreakyAli This doesn't work

I added the image file to my project and set the corresponding HeightRequest,
WidthRequest,
CornerRadius,
Padding,
Margin, the result is that the radian of the image is cropped correctly.  Did you try switching to a different image?

The format of the source image file may cause this problem, can you provide a reproducible sample which needs to contain your image file, I will try to reproduce your problem via sample.

@ShuowenHe-MSFT I think I can't give you a reproducible example without giving the code of the complete application. As you can see in the example, I use the same tag and with the same properties. It seems rather random.
